# bootstrapSwitch Don't toggle switch on click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I have a bootstrap switch, but I don't want it to toggle everytime. I want to check that a condition is true, and only then toggle the switch. How can I do that? This is what I have so far:

```
$("[name='relVal']").bootstrapSwitch({
    onSwitchChange: function(event, state) {
       if (condition_is_met) {
          $("[name='relVal']").bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
       }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://bttstrp.github.io/bootstrap-switch/options.html):

> onSwitchChange
>
> Callback function to execute on switch state change. If false is returned, the status will be reverted, otherwise nothing changes

So all you need to do is return `true/false` for the switch to actually happen or not.

```
$("[name='relVal']").bootstrapSwitch({
    onSwitchChange: function(event, state) {
        if (condition_is_met) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

        // Or as a one-liner
        // return condition_is_met;
    }
});
```